# Unity UI SVG Image цвет

Tags: unity3d, svg, gui, графика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я использую изображение в качестве UI SVG Image установленный цвет затмевает само изображение. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]